Ошибка SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL] record layer failure (_ssl.c:1147)
Всем привет! Столкнулась со следующей ошибкой :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/./add_status.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/./add_status.py", line 29, in main
    add_status(row[0], row[1])
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/bd_connect.py", line 63, in add_status
    status = send_request(ticket)
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/bd_connect.py", line 41, in send_request
    response = requests.get(url, headers=config["headers"], auth=(config["login"], config["password"]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 620, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx.xxx.xxx', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: xxx.xxx.xxx (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL] **record layer failure** (_ssl.c:1147)')))

До этого была другая ошибка, тоже связанная с SSL:
[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol

Но, я переустановила Python 3.9.20 и его библиотеки, обновила OpenSSl до версии 3.4.0.
И снова спотыкаюсь. Помогите!
Мой КОД:
import pymysql
import requests
from API_OTRS import set_dynamic_field

db_config = {
    "host": "xxx",
    "password": "xxxxx",
    "database": "xxxx"
}

config = {
    "url_format": "https://xxx.xxx.xxx{0}",
    "login": "xxxxx",
    "password": "xxxxx",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "contentType": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        #"X-Atlassian-Token": "no-check",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) "
                      "Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36",
    },
}

# запрос статуса
def send_request(ticket_number: str):
    url = str.format(config["url_format"], ticket_number)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=config["headers"], auth=(config["login"], config["password"]))
    if response.status_code == 200:
       json_result = response.json()
       status = json_result.get(['currentStatus'][0])
       return status['status']
    else:
       print(f"Ошибка: {response.status_code}: {response.content}")
       return


Код вызывающий данные ошибки добавить нужно...

я добавила код.

url корректный формируется? HTTPSConnectionPool может возникнуть из-за того, что программа пытается стучаться до неправильного адреса и таймауты кончаются. Попробуйте вывести url для проверки - совпадет ли он с тем, какой ожидает ваша система? Может / не хватает

Этот сайт открывается в браузере? Дело в том, что ошибка выглядит крайне экстравагантно. Получается, что сервер нарушает протокол TLS. Если браузер не сможет открыть сайт, то вот вам и кандидат в плохиши - сервер нерабочий. Если же браузер может открыть, а Пайтон нет, то это ... я бы сказал, невозможно )) Попробуйте для диагности открыть сервер в ручном режиме openssl s_client -connect <server_address>:443 . Когда все служебные надписи пройдут, напечатайте в приложении GET / HTTP/1.0 и посмотрите на результат. Если будет ошибка, то есть надежда что s_client напишет о ней больше.

И вообще, дайте адрес вашего сервера. Если удастся к нему подключиться, то диагностика будет более содержательной.
